# Make WebView more appealing with the xml content

Tags: android, webview, string-formatting

Well, I was making a application  in where I would be fetching data from a xml file and show it in a webView.

Previously I used TextView (But we can't justify the text that we set in that.) So, I used webView such that I can justify the text from the xml & I was able to do that but now the text content is not intact in the web view.

Suppose I want to show the below text content in the app.

[image]

Actually my requirement is in this way :

[image]

The way it gets displayed.

[image]

The code part which I am using for the content to get displayed

```
 final WebView storyViewText = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.storyView);

 String text = "<html><body>"+"<p align=\"justify\">"+getValue("text", eElement)+"</p>"+"</body></html>";
 storyViewText.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
 storyViewText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

The getValue() reads the xml and returns the whole as string.

How to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By default the formatting of the text is omitted in HTML (to separate semantics and structure).

To solve your problem you have two options:

1. Wrap the content of the text tag in a [`pre`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element) tag instead of the [`p`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) tag. This preserves your custom formatting.
2. Parse your text and add a [`p`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) tag per line manually.